# Ansible action not defined error

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, openstack

Im trying automate openstack istallation in ubuntu using ansible.
For Identity service(keystone Installation),

My task is to create a role "user" in keystone,

```
 - os_keystone_role:
          name: user
          state: present
```

But when i run my playbook,Im getting this error

```
   ERROR! no action detected in task
   The offending line appears to be:

   - os_user_role:
     ^ here
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What version of Ansible do you use?

Comment: The error messages of ansible are not that exact. They only marks the task, but the error must not be necessarily in that line. Please post a few more infos, like the playbook, and if possible the whole log.

Answer (score 0):

I would second @techraf's os_keystone_role module was new in Ansible verison 2.1, are you using version 2.1 or above?

I've seen this message come up when ansible does not recognize the module (either due to a typo or a newer module not recognized in an older version of ansible).